# onActivityResult function keeps image chooser up

Tags: java, android

In my android app, I allow the user to choose an image. The chosen image gets uploaded to a server and then shown in the view. The problem I'm experiencing is that once the user selects an image, the image choosing screen (that the shows all the thumbnails for the user to pick) doesn't get hidden until the image is uploaded to the server.

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int, android.os.Bundle)

`As a special case, if you call startActivityForResult() with a requestCode >= 0 during the initial onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)/onResume() of your activity, then your window will not be displayed until a result is returned back from the started activity. This is to avoid visible flickering when redirecting to another activity.`

So I made sure to use a `Runnable` to execute the image upload on a different thread. How can I get the image picker view to immediately be dismissed while my activity uploads the image?

Comment: If you fire the runnable or `AsyncTask` from within the calling applications `onActivityResult`, then you should be immediately returned to the calling application after the selection is made.  Is the runnable fired from within `onActivityResult`?  Perhaps I don't follow.

Comment: @JaySnayder, yes the runnable is called within the `onActivityResult` method.